# Trying to stream tweets in database using twitter API Python

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to retrieve tweets from twitter using a python script but every time I run the script I get the following error:

[image]

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import MySQLdb
import json

conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","lordstest")

c = conn.cursor()

ckey="kLqq9kLLnYzArceD7ymqlVEqS"
csecret="DxQQiynR13JYMgVf9ltCOHAM28Ai3gCzODIV3vj0OTIiKfShsz"

atoken="480488826-7iJ8Yq86ASy0u9HaSFO1ZCl5xlKakabKEsWaHVHh"
asecret="BJm6MdyrFRDObHc3sYSDqeStZYZlgIyHtRwFGzJ8XevdL"

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        all_data = json.loads(data)

        tweet = all_data["text"]

        username = all_data["user"]["screen_name"]

        c.execute("INSERT INTO Lords (username, tweet) VALUES (%s,%s)",
            (username, tweet))

        conn.commit()

        print((username,tweet))

        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["Lords test"],languages= ["en"])
```

Any help on how I can fix this?

Comment: Do you have network issues?

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are receiving? My understanding is if you are scraping you should put it into a nosql, like Mongo. I have [code on Github](https://github.com/miahunsicker/twitterbot/blob/master/twitter_to_mongo.py) that does so.